# Python Tesseract Error on Windows 8 machine

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have installed Python2.7, in my C:\Python27. This is added to Path in Environment Variables too.

I have numpy & OpenCV working. I do some basic image processing using it. Its working perfectly till date.

I have to work on OCR, and I tried to follow the instructions on installing Python-Tesseract from [here](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/), I have installed the 32-bit version.

I opened my Python, and when I do

```
    import tesseract
```

it imports without any error or problem.

But when I run a sample code, I get errors :

CODE

```
    import cv2.cv as cv
    import tesseract

    image=cv.LoadImage("eurotext.jpg", cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

    api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
    api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
    #api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_SINGLE_WORD)
    api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)
    tesseract.SetCvImage(image,api)
    text=api.GetUTF8Text()
    conf=api.MeanTextConf()
    image=None
    print text
    print conf
```

ERRORS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\Test\test.py", line 2, in <module>
import tesseract
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tesseract.py", line 28, in <module>
_tesseract = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tesseract.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_tesseract', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have looked at some stackoverflow questions, I could NOT follow most of it. I also tried re-installing it, which gave me the same errors.

If someone could guide me with this - it will be helpful.

Also, I know that the python-tesseract site says they support upto Windows-7. Unfortunately I have setup things on a Windows-8 machine, and I dont want to migrate. Again this error is seen on many places - but solution is highly difficult for a newbie like me to follow.

Comment: did you install the 64-bit version on a 32-bit Python installation?

Comment: Honestly, I dont remember & I dont know. I have tried to find this information. When I go to the Python site : https://www.python.org/downloads/ , there is NO option for 32-bit or 64-bit. I am assuming its 32-bit by default. Also, for python-tesseract, I have installed the 32-bit version. All this error was from the 32 bit version of python-tesseract.

Comment: I was able to only find a way to figure out what version of python was on my machine. I used `python -V` on my command line.

Comment: type `python` on the command line, and the startup banner will say whether it's 32- or 64-bit

Comment: Its a 32-bit version, I got this : 
`C:\Users\SKR>python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`. Thanks!

Comment: @Anonymus - whoever put a (-1) to my question, pls have the decency to explain the reason. I still need this fixed, and your (-1) will place my question really low. This is still a problem and I dont have a fix.